# How to get all exception handlers annotated by @ExceptionHanlder?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

How to get all exception handlers annotated by @ExceptionHanlder and I can call them manually?

**Background**
I need to handle some exceptions by my own exception handlers but in some situation my handled exceptions are not thrown directly by spring, and they are wrapped in the cause by. So I need to handle these caused by exceptions in one place using my own exception handling strategy in the existing `@ExceptionHandler`s. How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried handling the broad exception, then reading through the cause chain to implement the custom logic? Can you perhaps show your current exception handling method?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Java Reflection Api to find classes annotated with "ExceptionHanlder". And invoke any method or whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` and make it a `@ControllerAdvise` like below.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler({YourException.class})
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleMyException(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
            ... handle the way you like it
            return new ResponseEntity<Object>(YourErrorObject, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus);
    }
}
```

Comment: my question was the exceptions which I handled by `@ExceptionHandler` was wrapped by some another exception and how can I handle these exception using the existing logic.

Comment: In `@ExceptionHandler` annotation, put the exception that wraps the exception you want to handle. Inside the method you can check the original exception and execute the relevant logic.

Answer (score 0):

Spring provides `@ControllerAdvice` annotation that we can use with any class to define our global exception handler. The handler methods in Global Controller Advice is same as Controller based exception handler methods and used when controller class is not able to handle the exception.

You want to use exception handling strategy in your one place. that you can  define multiple exception or make message using exception in exception controller.

like this :

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = { HttpClientErrorException.class, HTTPException.class, HttpMediaTypeException.class,
            HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException.class, HttpMessageNotReadableException.class })
```

or

```
@ExceptionHandler
@ResponseBody
ExceptionRepresentation handle(Exception exception) {
    ExceptionRepresentation body = new ExceptionRepresentation(exception.getLocalizedMessage());
    HttpStatus responseStatus = resolveAnnotatedResponseStatus(exception);

    return new ResponseEntity<ExceptionRepresentation>(body, responseStatus);
}

HttpStatus resolveAnnotatedResponseStatus(Exception exception) {
    ResponseStatus annotation = findMergedAnnotation(exception.getClass(), ResponseStatus.class);
    if (annotation != null) {
        return annotation.value();
    }

    return HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
}
```

Comment: I have multiple `@ExceptionHandler` and also `@ControllerAdvice` however some exception is converted by spring or jpa's exception translator service. these exception was converted into another exception and the orginal exception was wrapped in the caused by. How can I handle these situation?

Comment: You make using common exception controller or need to handle your JPA service exception.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a work around. You can catch the the wrapping exception and then check the root cause of the exception. Here is an example of MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException which is wrapped by DataIntegrityViolationException in spring:

```
@ExceptionHandler(DataIntegrityViolationException.class)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<Object> proccessMySQLIntegrityConstraint(DataIntegrityViolationException exception) {
    if (exception.getRootCause() instanceof MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException) {
       doSomething....
    } else {
        doSomethingElse...
    }
}
```